# wordpress display only comments count

Tags: wordpress

Trying to display only the comments count a not the total including pingbacks and trackbacks

```
get_comments_number() // displays the total of comments, pingbacks and trackbacks
```

I tried using belows code but aint worked

```
count($wp_query->comments_by_type['comment']);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [get_comments function](https://codex.wordpress.org/get_comments) to do this.

```
$num_comments = get_comments(
    array(
        'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
        'type' => 'comment', 
        'count' => true // return only the count
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks again Matt, I added the code to comments.php and replaced get_comments_number() with $num_comments. Worked perfectly